# How should I properly assign a key and value pair?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript newbie. My code is working BUT I'm still getting this alert:

> should_properly_assign_key_and_value_pair, Expected 'string' to be
>   'object'.

Not sure how update current code to address this issue. Any advice? Thank you!

```
function transformFirstAndLast(array) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      result = (array[0] + ": " + array[array.length-1]);
      return result;
  }
}
console.log(transformFirstAndLast(['Kevin','Bacon','Spacey']));//Kevin : 'Spacey'
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code.

You are not showing where else it gets used or where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is expecting a key/value pair. Create a new object and set the data.

Change

```
result = (array[0] + ": " + array[array.length-1]);
```

to

```
var result = {};
result[array[0]] = array[array.length-1];

return result;
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with having a string result? What is expecting a key/value pair?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Nothing wrong with having a string result. The OP's code is doing what it is intending it to do. Just a possible solution for the warning that is displayed.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: Probably some kind of automated assignment checker.

Comment: Thanks Sushanth, your advice removed the alert. Thanks everyone for your  advice!

Comment: Where does the colon come from in the changed code?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what your code wants to do? The current code will always return the first element and the last element in the array with a ':' in middle, regardless how many other elements in the array. Is that your intention? If yes, I think you don't need to the loop, right? just return array[0] + ':' + array[arraly.length - 1] does the job for you..

If your intention is to concatenate the elements in the array, your code  need to be revised.